# make a sub defined in a module called by another module available to my script

Tags: perl

somehow I can't figure this one out... I've got a little perl-program thats using a perl module which is using an additional perl module - unknown to the initial perl-program. Although that additional perl-module does export it's sub it's not visible to the perl-prog. Only the directly called pm does see it.

this is my perlprog.pl

```
use Modern::Perl;

use lib '.';
use direct;

hello1( 'test 1' );
hello2( 'test 2' );
```

this is direct.pm

```
use Modern::Perl;

package direct;

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = ( 'hello1' );
our %EXPORT = ( all=>[ 'hello1' ] );

use lib '.';
use additional;

sub hello1
{
    say sprintf 'Hello ONE got "%s"', join ',', @_;
}

1;
```

and this is additional.pm

```
use Modern::Perl;

package additional;

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = ( 'hello2' );
our %EXPORT = ( all=>[ 'hello2' ] );

sub hello2
{
    say sprintf 'Hello TWO got "%s"', join ',', @_;
}

1;
```

I don't want to touch my perlprog.pl or direct.pm

I'd like to know what I have to do in additional.pm to make hello2 available to perlprog.pl as soon as additional.pm is used anywhere.

How can I do that?

Googling for that wasn't very helpful and I couldn't figure it out from the docpages.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `use lib` in modules. If Perl can find the module, you don't need to tell it where to find modules!

Comment: Tip: `all=>[ 'hello1' ]` could be written as `all=>\@EXPORT` to adhere to DRY.

Comment: Tip: `use lib '.';` is a bug. It should be `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;`. `.` is the CWD. `$RealBin` is the script's directory

Answer (score 2):

The following will export `hello2` to the default namespace (`main`):

```perl
*main::hello2 = \&additional::hello2;
```

This is a horrible practice. What you should do is modify direct.pm so that its `@EXPORT` contains `hello2`.

```perl
our @EXPORT = qw( hello1 hello2 );
# -or-
our @EXPORT = ( 'hello1', @additional::EXPORT );
```

Comment: Note that additional.pm can't modify `@direct::EXPORT` itself since the `our @EXPORT = ( 'hello1' );` assignment in direct.pm has yet to be executed and will overwrite the addition. But this too would be a horrible practice.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting `hello2` from `additional`. When you use `additional` in the `direct` package, it's imported into its namespace, i.e. `direct::hello2` now exists and is the same as `additional::hello2`.

When you use `direct`, you export `hello1`, so `direct::hello1` can be now accessed as `main::hello1`.

But there's nothing going on to make either `additional::hello2` or `direct::hello2` available as `main::hello2`.

So, you either need to import `hello2` into the main script from `additional`, or export it from `direct`.

Comment: Hmmm... I was afraid that there actually isn't a solution. At least not a clean one. The only thing I could think of is adding that to additional.pm:
`sub ::hello2 { \&hello2( @_ ) };`
It works, but it's unclean as...
Anyway... thank you for your lightning fast reply. It's good to know that there are still other Perl hackers out there ;-)